# Is it possible to disable wait time for watir?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I'm writing a script that registers users for me, but the website got a lot of junk loading (like statistic urls that has to load in etc) so the script is really slow cause its waiting for the site to fully load even if all the elements needed already are loaded, is it possible to disable this wait time=? it would make my script like 10 sec faster.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which browser you are on so that you can add some options to ignore those loadings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The waiting for the page to load is controlled by the page load strategy. By default, it is set to "normal", which waits for the document readiness state to be "complete". You can set the strategy to "none" to remove the waiting. Some of the browsers/drivers also support an "eager" strategy that waits for the browser to be in the "interactive" state.

```
require 'webdrivers'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, page_load_strategy: 'none'
browser.goto 'www.google.com'
p browser.ready_state
#=> "loading"
```

See https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#navigation for more details.

Comment: Hi, Is this a new feature? I have never heard of this.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, it's new enough that it is not yet fully supported by all drivers. However, it has been around for over a year (not sure the exact point it was introduced).