# How to make Selenium NOT wait until the page is ready?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am scraping a web page with Selenium (specifically https://gamh.com/calendar/),

running `driver.navigate.to(url)` and it never gets past this line, it throws a `Net::ReadTimeout`.

The thing is, I can *see* that the page is ready, it's actually ready after just a few seconds. I don't know what is preventing Selenium from thinking the page is ready, but I want to make it stop.

How can I prevent Selenium's default behavior, of waiting until the page is completely ready? I don't want to raise the timeout because it's totally unnecessary.

Comment: Here is the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56064566/9043475 .

Comment: Thank you @Rajagopalan feel free to mark the question as duplicate

Comment: You are welcome. No, this question is useful in selenium section so need not to mark it as duplicate

Comment: Yes @Rajagopalan it can still be in the selenium section, marking it as duplicate is just how we can make it not be unanswered anymore

Comment: Since watir is based on selenium it's all the same

Comment: All right. That's okay with me